# How can I use find extention function in kotlin and have it's index in the lambda

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list of strings. I'm using Kotlin with Android. I want to find a specific string which matches a condition, I want to know :

- if that string exists
- if it does what's the index

Also, this is the code I wrote but it's not optimized cause using `find` and `indexOf` is `O(n^2)`

```
list.find { it == "slug"}
    ?.also{
           // do some logic
           list2.add(list.indexOf("slug")
          }
```

Comment: val myString = list.firstOrNull {it== "slug"}
myString?.let{list2.add(it)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `indexOf` in the first place. It returns `-1` if element is not found, so you can either check it inside your `also` block or turn it into nullable with `takeIf`:

```
list.indexOf("slug").takeIf{ it > -1 }?.also {
    //do some logic
    list2.add(it)
}
```

tip: if your list is sorted you might want to use [binary search](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/binary-search.html) instead of `indexOf` for better performance.

Comment: I want to use the condition also. I've made the problem simple to post on here. but the condition isn't really `it== "slug"`

Comment: in that case replace `indexOf` with [`indexOfFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html)

Comment: Yes, that works now. You could edit your answer so other people can use it too. Thanks.